# vb.net datagridview error message

Tags: vb.net

I'm Validating my DataGridView cells on CellValidated event & CellEndEdit events. Errors are triggered & error message also displayed when I pressed Tab key & cursor moves to next cell.

I want to know how I move my cell to error column & error row (stop the cursor on the error cell).

My Code is like this.

```
Private Sub dgDataGrid _CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgDataGrid.CellEndEdit

    If dgPettyCashEnter.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "Account" Then ' Validating Account Number
        Dim odcCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("<Stored Procedure>", <Connection>)
        ' Stored Procedure Process
        Dim <odrDataReader> As OleDbDataReader = odcCommand.ExecuteReader()
        Do While odrDataReader.Read
            If CInt(odrDataReader.GetValue(0)) = 0 Then
                dgDataGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Account No Not Found. Invalid Account No."
                intCol = e.ColumnIndex
                intRow = e.RowIndex
                booErrorFire = True
            Else
                dgDataGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = ""
                booErrorFire = False
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub dgDataGrid _CellValidated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgDataGrid.CellValidated
    Try
        If dgDataGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "Account" Then ' Validating Account Number
            If CStr(dgDataGrid (2, e.RowIndex).Value).Length > 6 Or CStr(dgDataGrid (2, e.RowIndex).Value).Length = 0 Then ' Account Code Length Invalid
                dgDataGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Account Code Length Invalid"
                intCol = e.ColumnIndex
                intRow = e.RowIndex
                booErrorFire = True
            Else ' Account Code Length Valid
                dgDataGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = ""
                booErrorFire = False
            End If
        Else
            dgDataGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = ""
            booErrorFire = False
        End If
    Catch ex As NullReferenceException
        If dgDataGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "Account" Then
            dgDataGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Account Code Length Invalid"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: You are supposed to perform validation in the `CellValidating` event handler. If the cell fails validation you set `e.Cancel` to `True` and the caret will remain in that cell. Neither of the events you are handling are intended for actual validation. `CellEndEdit` is for doing something after EVERY edit and `CellValidated` is for doing something if and only if `e.Cancel` is NOT set to `True` in `CellValidating`.

Comment: Cannot get cell value length from CellValidating event. Eg. If dgDataGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "Account" Then ' Validating Account Number
                If CStr(dgDataGrid(2, e.RowIndex).Value).Length > 6 Or CStr(dgDataGrid(2, e.RowIndex).Value).Length = 0 Then
                    dgDataGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Account Code Length Invalid"
                    dgDataGrid(("Account"), (e.RowIndex)).Selected = True
                Else
                    dgDataGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = ""
                End If

Comment: jmcilhinney Thank You. I found my error. Again Thank you lot.